# importing java lib in clojure, how does it work?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to build my first clojure leiningen project but I have an issue using a specific java class in my code.

While coding, I was looking for a specific functionnality and found out about DatatypeConverter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html).
Then I had to figure how to import the library. I don't know anything about Maven but I ended up somewhat (educated?) guessing I should looking for the library there https://search.maven.org/.

So there is what I ended up writing for my project.clj file:

```
(defproject game-backend "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :main game-backend.core
  :dependencies [
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api "2.2.12"]
                 ])
```

and here is my ns macro call in my core.clj file:

```
(ns game-backend.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io])
  (:import
   (java.security DigestInputStream)
   (java.io FileInputStream)
   (javax.xml.bind DataTypeConverter)
  )
)
```

and when I tun `lein run` I get the following error (a package was downloaded at some point in time): `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DataTypeConverter, compiling:(game_backend/core.clj:1:1)`

I(m have no idea how many steps I've done wrong (all of them?). Can you please enlight me on how it should be done?

Comment: Have you tried `lein clean` `lein deps` since you added `[javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api "2.2.12"]` to your project.clj file?

Comment: I did after seeing your comment but it didn't help (and nothing new as downloaded).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a lowercase 't'  [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html)

```
(ns game-backend.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io])
  (:import
   (java.security DigestInputStream)
   (java.io FileInputStream)
   (javax.xml.bind DatatypeConverter)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look inside your maven repository (.m2 directory). You will be able to find the jar file there. Then look at the .class files in that jar.

```
DatatypeConverter.class
```

That's one way to find that you should be using a lowercase 't'.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add multiple classes of a package:

```
(:import (java.io File Bits BufferedInputStream))
```